# Want to go on first page With the help of arrow-left in kivymd

Tags: python, kivy-language, kivymd

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.toolbar import MDTopAppBar
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

KV = '''

ScreenManagement:

    id: screen_manager
    MainScreen:
    SettingsScreen:
        
<MainScreen>:

    name:'main'

    MDBoxLayout:

        orientation:'vertical'
        
        padding: 5, 6, 5, 6
    
        MDTopAppBar:
            title: "Learning"
            elevation: 5

            md_bg_color:0.6,.1,.2,1

            left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_draw.set_state()]]

        FitImage:

            size_hint_y:1
            source: 'a6.jpeg'
            padding: 0, 5, 0, 5

        MDLabel:
           
            text:'Welcome'
            halign:'center'
            color:'black'
            md_bg_color:0.5,.1,.2,1
            font_style:'H3'

        MDGridLayout:

            md_bg_color:0,0,0,1
            rows:2
            padding: 8, 8, 8, 8
            Button:

                text:'Python'
                color:'pink'
                background_color: 0.2, 0.7, 0, 1

            Button:

                text:'C++'
                color:'pink'
                background_color: 0.2, 0.7, 0, 1

            Button:

                text:'Java'
                color:'pink'
                background_color: 0.2, 0.7, 0, 1

            Button:

                text:'Php'
                color:'pink'
                background_color: 0.2, 0.7, 0,1 

    Widget:

    MDNavigationDrawer:

        id: nav_draw
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding: "8dp"
        spacing: "8dp"
      
        AnchorLayout:

            anchor_x: "left"
            size_hint_y: None
            height: avatar.height

            Image:

                id: avatar
                size_hint: None, None
                size: "150dp", "150dp"
                source: "demo.png"

        MDLabel:

            text: "Teacher"
            font_style: "Button"
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]

        MDLabel:

            text: "youremail@gmail.com"
            font_style: "Caption"
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]

        ScrollView:

            MDList:

                OneLineAvatarListItem:

                    on_press:
                        nav_draw.set_state("close")

                    text: "Home"

                    IconLeftWidget:

                        icon: "home"

                OneLineAvatarListItem:

                    on_press:
                        nav_draw.set_state("close")

                    text: "Courses"

                    IconLeftWidget:

                        icon: "school"

               
                OneLineAvatarListItem:

                    on_press:
                        nav_draw.set_state("close")

                    text: "Rate app"

                    IconLeftWidget:

                        icon: 'star'

                OneLineAvatarListItem:

                    on_press:
                        nav_draw.set_state("close")

                    text: "About"

                    IconLeftWidget:

                        icon: 'information'

                OneLineAvatarListItem:

                    on_press:

                        app.root.current = 's_screen' 

                    text:'Settings'

                    IconLeftWidget:

                        icon: 'cog'                      

        Widget:

<SettingsScreen>:

    name: "s_screen"

    MDBoxLayout:

        orientation:'vertical'

        MDTopAppBar:

            title:"Settings"
            pos_hint: {"top": 1}
            elevation: 5
            left_action_items: [["arrow-left", lambda x: app.callback()]]
'''

class MainScreen(Screen):

    pass

class SettingsScreen(Screen):

    pass

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):

    pass

class Main(MDApp):

    def build(self):

        return Builder.load_string(KV)

        

Main().run()
```

I an new in python and want to go on first page With the help of arrow-left
But it didn't work

Comment: please amend the syntax errors in the code (editing of question) so
that other users can reproduce the problem quickly:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example